# Issues when group join 3 table

Tags: c#, linq

Please help me resolve this issue. I still can not understand how it throw exception "system.linq.systemcore_enumerabledebugview evaluation time out" when debuging

```
var mealDataDetail = ( _dbContext.Meal.Where(m => m.IsDeleted == 0 && m.UserId == userId).ToList()
                           .GroupJoin(_dbContext.MealImage.Where(i => i.IsDeleted == 0  && i.MealType == (int)mealType).ToList(), p => p.Id, r => r.MealId, (p, rs) => new { p, rs })
                           .GroupJoin(_dbContext.MealMenu.Where(i => i.IsDeleted == 0 && i.MealType == (int)mealType).ToList(), prs => prs.p.Id, c => c.MealId, (prs, cs) => new MealDataDetail
                           {
                               MealId = prs.p.Id,

                               MealData = new MealData
                               {
                                   MealImages = prs.rs.Select(im => im.Image),
                                   Description = prs.p.BreakfastDescription,
                                   Time = prs.p.BreakfastTime,
                                   TimeRequired = prs.p.BreakfastTimeRequired,
                                   Appitite = prs.p.BreakfastAppetite,
                                   Status = prs.p.BreakfastStatus == 1,
                                   Calorie = prs.p.BreakfastCalorie,
                               },
                           }));
```

Comment: Why are you doing a `ToList` before the joins?

Comment: How long does it take for the error to occur?  How large is your database? The normal default setting when querying a database is 30 seconds.  You may need to increase the timeout.

Comment: Use a a database profiler, to see what its doing, however you should seriously reconsider your ToList() shenanigans

Answer (score 0):

Was it supposed to be a single query?
Keep in mind that your .ToList() is executing the query at that moment.
Try removing the ToList() but I suggest you rewrite it once the database is getting a really monster query. Is better to have a procedure instead